# gcloud compute ssh — avoid having to 2FA every time?

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I use `gcloud compute ssh` to SSH into my instance, e.g.:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh shell-server --project=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-f] for instance: [shell-server].
External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
Please choose from the available authentication methods:
1: Security code from Google Authenticator application
2: Voice or text message verification code

Enter the number for the authentication method to use: 1
Enter your one-time password: XXXXXX
username@shell-server ~ $
```

Unfortunately, I have to 2FA every time.  I like 2FA, but maybe there's a way to set things up so that I only have to provided it every few hours?

**Update:** I ran `gcloud compute ssh --dry-run`, which tells you exactly what command it's running:

```
/usr/bin/ssh \
    -t \
    -i /Users/kannan/.ssh/google_compute_engine \
    -o CheckHostIP=no \
    -o HostKeyAlias=compute.123123123123123123 \
    -o IdentitiesOnly=yes \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/kannan/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts \
    -o ProxyCommand='/usr/local/bin/python3 -S /Users/kannan/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel shell-server %p --listen-on-stdin --project=XXXXXXXXXX --zone=us-central1-f --verbosity=warning' \
    -o ProxyUseFdpass=no \
    kannan_example_org@compute.123123123123123123
```

**Update 2**: I could keep `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel` running in the background and configure my SSH to use that tunnel, but I'm hoping for something more automatic, similar to the convenience of SSH's `ControlMaster=auto`.

Comment: Which service is providing MFA/2FA/2-Step-Verfication?

Comment: @JohnHanley: Good question.  I think it's GCP's "IAP Tunnel" feature that asks for 2FA.  I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Actually, I was wrong.  It's actually the target instance itself ("shell-server") that asks for 2FA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Put this in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host shell-server
    User kannan_example_org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    CheckHostIP no
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ProxyCommand gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel %n %p --project="..." --zone="..." --listen-on-stdin --verbosity=warning
    ProxyUseFdpass no
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 30m
```

- `ControlMaster auto`: On every `ssh`/`scp` invocation, first check if there's an existing connection to `shell-server`.  If so, just share that connection, so there's no re-auth and therefore no re-2FA.
- `ControlPersist 30m` tells SSH that even after all `ssh`/`scp` invocations are done, keep the sharable connection open for 30m.

I can now just use plain `ssh` and `scp` commands with the hostname `shell-server`.

Note: I actually ended up setting `ProxyCommand` to a custom wrapper script that automatically determines `--project=...` and `--zone=...` from the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

The 2FA is a part of the OS Login service. Could you verify by the command below whether you have the flag set up for a project?

gcloud compute project-info describe | grep os

If it's enabled you may disable it for the entire project or during the creation of a VM.

More info here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin

I hope it will help.

Comment: Oh sorry -- to be clear I don't want to disable 2FA.  I just don't want to have to type it in on every new `ssh` (or `scp`) invocation.  For example, maybe it could only ask for 2FA every 24 hours.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not feasible to do in the OS Login service. There is no switch in the command line to set up a timeout.